# Show content of a process descriptor

Tags: linux-kernel

I was wondering if there is a way to print/show the content of a particular running process descriptor. I know that the kernel maintains those information in a task_struct. Is it possible to print that from the terminal?

This is just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

See the entries under `/proc/pid/` (where `pid` is the numeric process ID) on the [proc man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: I think that @mustafa means https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7e7814180b334dff97ef8f56c7c40c277ad4531c/include/linux/sched.h#L1460

Comment: That is to see the file descriptors. I am asking about the process descriptors http://linuxgazette.net/133/saha.html

Comment: @mustafa You won't see the internal kernel data structure unless you use a kernel debugger, but most of the information is in various files under `/proc/[pid]`. `man 5 proc` gives an overview.